# how to retrieve value of an object in RDF when we have subject and properties using jena without sparql?

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web, jena, ontology

I want to retrieve my RDF statement's object value and I know how to iterate all of my classes and their respective properties but I don't know how can I access to their objects?

for example :

```
OntModel rdfModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        rdfModel.read("mydata.rdf").read("myontology.rdf");
ExtendedIterator<OntClass> instances =  rdfModel.listClasses();
        while(instances.hasNext())
        {

            OntClass cls = instances.next();
            System.out.println("class name :" + cls.getURI());

            ExtendedIterator<OntProperty> prop = rdfModel.listOntProperties();
            while(prop.hasNext())
            {
                OntProperty ppp = prop.next();
                if (ppp.hasDomain(cls))
                {
                    System.out.println("the properties are :" + ppp.getURI());
                }
            }
```

now I want to have access to each and every object which have a relation to a property of an interated class.

how should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OntClass.listProperties(Property).  [Javadocs](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html) are your friend.